# How to remove dropdown and add input text field on specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have country and state dropdowns on a form. I want state dropdown to automatically change into an input text field when country is selected as US. I could write this code so far

```
$(function(){
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var selected=$(this).find("option:selected").val();
    if(selected=='US'){
     //need to write some code to change the dropdown into input text field
    }
});
})
```

Can't think of any code inside if block to change the state dropdown into input text.
How can I change the dropdown into input text field upon dynamic selection?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just always have the input text field there but hidden and show it to user upon having `US` selected?

Comment: @SnoopFrog how can I show it instead of dropdown? Please guide..

Comment: I am thinking about it from UX standpoint, because if you turn the dropdown into a text input, how is person supposed to change back from US to something else if they selected US by a mistake? Can you please provide part of your HTML code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the jQuery css property to require displaying or hiding elements, so you can hide or show the input box or another drop down... like so

```js
$(function(){
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var selected=$(this).find("option:selected").val();
    if(selected=='US'){
        $('#us_text').css('display', "block")
        $('#cities').css('display', "none")
    } else {
        $('#us_text').css('display', "none")
        $('#cities').css('display', "block")
    }
});

}).jQuery
```

```css
#us_text {
display:none;
}
#cities {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option selected>-- Select --</option>
  <option value="US">us</option>
  <option value="GB">GB</option>
  <option value="CA">CA</option>
</select>
<input id="us_text" type="text" />
<select id="cities">
  <option value="city1">city1</option>
  <option value="city2">citey2</option>
</select>
```